# Once a visable network has been constructed in the u.i will it be possible to have turtles visably travelling along these connections?

Tags: netlogo

For the model I wish to build it is important that the user can visualise the flow of turtles( shape "car") around a network. The network is currently very basic in that it is just links connecting nodes, however I wish to know firstly if what I describe would be possible and secondly how I would go about this should the first condition be met. I should also note that I wish for the behaviour of the turtles to be the same as the behaviour in traffic 2 lanes. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In NetLogo's Models Library, under Code Examples, have a look at Move Towards Target Example. It shows how to move turtles from node to node.  (In the example, there aren't any links, but the principle is the same.)